# Why is python psutil.wait_procs imposing its own timeout?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use subprocess.Popen to spawn several subprocesses, and psutil.wait_procs to wait for them to complete. The processes all seem to run, but the wait_procs doesn't seem to have worked. My callback isn't executed and I get a timeoput message from the first process, even though I've set timeout=None. I guess that I must be doing something wrong :(

Here's the script that launches several subprocesses:

```
(plot) $ cat multi-run.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import psutil
import random

def on_completion(proc):
    print("Pid %d completed" % proc.pid)

random.seed(1234)
procs = []
for i in range(2):
    soh = open('out%s.txt' % i, 'w')
    seh = open('err%s.txt' % i, 'w')
    sleepfor = random.randrange(1, 4) 
    myargs = ['./subproc.py', '%s' % sleepfor, 'SO%s' % i , 'SE%s' % i]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(myargs, stdout=soh, stderr=seh)
    procs.append(proc)
psutil.wait_procs(procs, timeout=None, callback=on_completion)
```

And here's the subproc.py script for the subprocesses:

```
(plot) $ cat subproc.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time
from sys import argv, stderr
print("Sleeping for %s seconds" % argv[1])
print("Second arg to stdout: '%s'" % argv[2]);
print("Third arg to stderr: '%s'" % argv[3], file=stderr);
time.sleep(float(argv[1]))
```

Both are meant to be in the same directory. When I run

```
$ ./multi-run.py
```

I get the following output:

```
(plot) $ ./multi-run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multi-run.py", line 18, in <module>
    psutil.wait_procs(procs, timeout=None, callback=on_completion)
  File "/Users/XXXX/anaconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 1561, in wait_procs
    check_gone(proc, max_timeout)
  File "/Users/XXXX/anaconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 1524, in check_gone
    returncode = proc.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/XXXX/anaconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1561, in wait
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '['./subproc.py', '2', 'SO0', 'SE0']' timed out after 0.5 seconds
```

I'm running Python 3.4.5 and psutil 5.0.1

Comment: It appears to me that the wait loop in wait_procs is using os.wait with a small timeout, according to the comments to "avoid waiting to long on one process. Isn't the right way to do this with a non-blocking wait? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are NOT passing psutil.wait_procs() a list of psutil.Process() instances, which is what it expects. Instead you are passing subprocess.Popen() instances. 
Your script does not error out because incidentally subprocess.Popen() also exposes a wait() method, which is what psutil.wait_procs() relies on internally, but it's just an accident. 
This demonstrates a weakness in psutil though which should be nicer, check the passed instances and error out immediately if they're not an instance of psutil.Process. I will file a bug and fix that in psutil.

Comment: Thanks, I obviously hadn't read docs thoroughly enough. "Popen" sounds like a verb, not a noun, and I didn't imagine that there would two entirely different python abstractions of a process object. I wish that there were a convenience method like your wait_procs that runs on a list of Popen instances, or in the alternative, that I had control over the "plumbing" (stdout and stderr) of a psutil.Process. Or am I still missing something?